# how to log to your own log table using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am writing a SSIS package and tying to implement logging. I am aware that SSIS has it inbuilt logging system. What I need is that the logs be captured and written to my own custom table. The custom table does not match the SSIS log table. I will need to capture relevant information to my table.

How do I go about that.

Comment: Do I need to write a SQL job that will poll the table every minute for example and retrieve information if package failed

Comment: How much work do you want to do? You can write your own custom logging components in .NET or you can attached Execute SQL Tasks to Event Handlers within SSIS and perform your inserts there.

Comment: If you can narrow the scope of your question, that'd be advisable. Otherwise, it's likely to get closed as too broad

Comment: I am looking forward for logging to custom table . That's all. How do I go about it

Answer (score 0):

This is too broad to answer however I have implemented custom logging through **Event Handlers** to log an event/Control flow task

- Create a reusable script task to log Error/Info/Warning to table.
- Create a reusable script task just to log that certain events occurred.
- Set this Script task to specific Events on Events Handlers.

*If you want custom logging at DFT Transformation Level, you may have to use script component only.*

Comment: Is there some example to share

Comment: I am having 20 execute tasks on the control flow . I wane to be able to log error if it occurs in any of these tasks

Comment: @Tom - You need to configure Event Handler on Error event of all Execute Tasks. Once Error Event occurs, pass System:ErrorCode and ErrorDescription variables to logging through script task as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can log information to your own table using an `Execute SQL Task`.

Comment: How do I capture that log information before inserting into table

Comment: Well that's a different and unanswerable question.  Depends what log information you want to capture.   Mostly it will involve populating variables in script tasks.

Comment: I didnt meant what log information to capture. I am looking at the mechanism on how it is done

Comment: Ok, well, use script tasks to populate variables with the information you want to capture.